# Analogue of disjunction and existence properties for a Turing-complete programming language?

Tags: logic, curry-howard, continuations

Quoting [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_and_existence_properties):

> In mathematical logic, the disjunction and existence properties are
> the "hallmarks" of constructive theories such as Heyting arithmetic
> and constructive set theories (Rathjen 2005).
>
> The disjunction property is satisfied by a theory if, whenever a
> sentence `A ∨ B` is a theorem, then either `A` is a theorem, or `B` is a
> theorem.
>
> The existence property or witness property is satisfied by a theory
> if, whenever a sentence `(∃x)A(x)` is a theorem, where `A(x)` has no other
> free variables, then there is some term `t` such that the theory proves
> `A(t)`.

In the realm of logic [to the best of my understanding], these properties are violated when a logic is "classical", which, through the Curry-Howard lens, corresponds to it having support for capturing undelimited continuations.

For Turing-complete programming languages, the presence or absence of first-class control and undelimited continuations is also a meaningful and important distinction. However, being inconsistent as logics, the disjunction and existence properties in their above form hold trivially: every 'sentence' is a 'theorem'.

So: Is there any formal property that can distinguish Turing-complete programming languages based on whether or not they have undelimited continuations, which is similar in spirit to the disjunction and existence properties for logics? (Let's assume the languages are statically typed and do possess sum types and/or existential types.)